# sharing Data between a UIViewController and a UIViewController in UITabBarController xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I know how to do for share data between 2 views. But if I want to share data using a tabBarController I'm lost.

This is my IBAction to move to my tabBar.

```
-(IBAction)goToPage2:(id)sender
{
 tabController.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
 [self presentModalViewController:tabController animated:YES];
}
```

i need to share my NSString *dataStr in my IBAction in the first view of my tabBar.

```
firstView *first = [[firstView alloc] initWithNibName:@"firstView" bundle:nil];
first.dataStr = name.text;
[tabController  presentModalViewController:first animated:YES];
```

this code doesn't work.

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a @property in your app delegate. And you can access your app delegate from any point of your app.

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate =  (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication ]delegate]
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree with what Terente suggested. But I recommend you should use a Data Class in this case. Using a property in Appdelegate is not a good practice. You should always use Data Class for this.
You create a Data class as follows:
You need to create a Data class where you can set the properties of variables or in your case arrays (for displaying data in UITableView). Implement a class method in data class which checks that object has been instantiated or not. If not, it does that. It is something like this :

//DataClass.h

```
@interface DataClass : NSObject {  

NSMutableArray *nameArray;  
NSMutableArray *placeArray;     

}  
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *nameArray;  
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *placeArray;  
+(DataClass*)getInstance;  
@end
```

//DataClass.m

```
@implementation DataClass  
@synthesize nameArray;  
@synthesize placeArray;  
static DataClass *instance =nil;  
+(DataClass *)getInstance  
{  
    @synchronized(self)  
    {  
        if(instance==nil)  
        {  

            instance= [DataClass new];  
        }  
    }  
    return instance;  
}
```

Now in your view controller you need to call this method as :

```
DataClass *obj=[DataClass getInstance];
```

And use the arrays.
This way you can assign data without disturbing AppDelegate, which is a good practice.

Comment: Yeah sure. If you find it correct upvote the answer and accept it :))

Comment: @Nitish I'm trying to use your example to create a data class in order to share an array of calendar events between a MainViewController, and a SecondViewController, which happens to be a table view. How exactly would I go about "setting" the array itself, in order to access it with `DataClass *obj=[DataClass getInstance];`?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a lengthy tutorial about such issues on my blog: http://www.hollance.com/2011/04/making-your-classes-talk-to-each-other-part-1/

You need to figure out a clean way to let your controllers communicate with each other. My tutorial explains several ways to do this and what the advantages and downsides are of each approach. It's worth learning how to do this, because this issue comes up in almost any app you will write.